# No PDO Error, but transaction fails (properly)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a table with a constraint that prevents some combinations of variables from being inserted, however, when I execute insert with bad values from inside transaction, the insert fails (as it should), but the `PDOException` isn't raised. In fact, the transaction acts as if it committed successfully, however the following select shows that the values weren't inserted (just for the record, the correct combination of values are inserted using the same function). What is going wrong?

Below is the offending function. `db_SqlSrv::pdo()` creates and returns a new instance of `PDO`, I'm using sqlsrv drivers.

```
/**
 * Inserts number of rules into <code>menu_availability</code> table.
 * The expected format for rules is:
 * <code>[{ menu_id: int,
 *          start: timestring,
 *          end: timestring,
 *          weekly: 0..6,
 *          once: datestring }, ...]</code>
 */
public static function addRules() {
    $rules = web_Util::getRequestParam('rules', 'json');
    if ($rules !== null) {
        $pdo = db_SqlSrv::pdo();
        try {
            $pdo->beginTransaction();
            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $statement = $pdo->prepare(
                    "insert into menu_availability
                     (menu_id, daily_serving_start, daily_serving_end,
                     weekly_service_off, one_time_service_off)
                     values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $statement->bindParam(1, $rule->menu_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                if ($rule->start) {
                    $statement->bindParam(2, $rule->start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $statement->bindParam(3, $rule->end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                } else {
                      // This feels kind of stupid...
                    $rule->start = null;
                    $rule->end = null;
                    $statement->bindParam(2, $rule->start, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                    $statement->bindParam(3, $rule->end, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
                }
                $statement->bindParam(4, $rule->weekly, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $statement->bindParam(5, $rule->once, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->execute();
            }
            $pdo->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $pdo->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how the table is defined:

```sql
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'menu_availability' and xtype = 'U')
create table menu_availability
   (menu_id int not null,
    daily_serving_start time(0) null,
    daily_serving_end time(0) null,
    weekly_service_off tinyint null,
    one_time_service_off date null,
    sn as case
       when ((daily_serving_start is null
              and daily_serving_end is null)
             and ((weekly_service_off is not null and one_time_service_off is null)
                  or (one_time_service_off is not null and weekly_service_off is null)))
            or
            ((daily_serving_start is not null
              and daily_serving_end is not null)
             and (one_time_service_off is null
                  or weekly_service_off is null))
             then cast(1 as bit)
        end persisted not null,
    constraint ch_valid_week_day
    check ((weekly_service_off is null)
        or (weekly_service_off <= 6 and weekly_service_off >= 0)));
```

Example data that should trigger constraint restriction:

```
{"menu_id":"18283","start":"","end":"","weekly":3,"once":"16-01-1901"}
```

*(it's illegal to give both `weekly` and `once`)*

Comment: Obvious point, but are you sure you've configured PDO to throw exceptions? `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: You should move your prepare statement out of the `foreach` loop. You only need to prepare it once.

Comment: No problem, just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO requires that you explicitly tell it to throw exceptions when errors occur. By default it will not trigger errors and it will not throw exceptions, it expects you to check for errors manually using [`PDO::errorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), and their equivalents on [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

By calling [`PDO::setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) you can change this behaviour, generally I do this whenever I set up a PDO connection:

```
$db = new PDO($myDSN);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

When you do this, PDO will throw exceptions whenever it encounters an error.

It is also worth noting that connection errors will always throw exceptions regardless of this setting, since the connection is made in the constructor, and exceptions are really the only way to handle this - you obviously cannot call a method of an object that has not yet been instantiated. This is a good example of one of the reasons why constructors should generally not contain business logic, it massively reduces flexibility in such situations.